# Justifications for using MSSQL over MySQL from cost perspective

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server

I'm in the process of switching from certain open-source technologies to ASP.net for building web applications (including some complex CRM and ERP tools as well as simple blog-like apps.) So far I've used MSSQL in the learning process but the more time I spend looking into infrastructure costs, the less impressed I am with MSSQL. (Windows Server / IIS on the other hand is relatively inexpensive and not a concern.) I've used MySQL in the past and feel comfortable with it.

Please provide me examples of situations, if any, where given the choice, MSSQL would justify its costs compared to MySQL. I realize there are reasons to use MSSQL such as the quality of integration out-of-the-box with Visual Studio, etc -- however I'm more interested in this from the stand-point of the raw costs of running servers. For example, if you can tell me something like "the license cost of MSSQL with one physical server will be lower than the hardware costs of running multiple servers with MySQL while providing the same performance in situation X, Y, and Z," I'd love to hear it. Perhaps there are reasons why it's cheaper to scale MSSQL or perhaps it is just a lot more efficient. People make the decision to choose MSSQL every day and I'd like to hear the reasons that pertain to cost.

I also welcome any answers that prove the costs to be negligible.

Comment: This is a good question. SQL Server, Standard Edition is priced at about $7000 per cpu. Workgroup Edition is about half that. (http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/get-sql-server/how-to-buy.aspx) I'm not familiar with MySQL features, but I'm curious about the answers here.

Comment: MySQL and MSSQL are very different beasts, perhaps postgreSQL is a better choice, it's closer to MSSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your MySQL will scale much more than the limitations of Express, than perhaps you shouldn't use MySQL at all. 
SQL Server is licensed Per CAL or Per CPU Socket(most expensive). There are also cheaper versions with fewer features but still fully functional, namely Web edition and Workgroup edition.
If money is your sole concern here, I encourage you to check [the edition compare](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx) and see the one that best satisfy your needs then check the [licensing info](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/get-sql-server/how-to-buy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Sql Express? There are few limits (1gb ram, 4gb db) but besides that you can get the management tools for it, etc.
Voila - no cost : )

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason is those limits are way too low.

Comment: And it is 10GB for a database in 2008 R2. We use it for a forum that gets about 150,000 unique visitors a month with zero problems.